# analysing memory usage by a function in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, memory-management, memory-leaks

Is there any inbuilt feature of eclipe that allows us to track how much space is beign taken by a particular function.Some pointers of anyalying memory uses in eclipe will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) (MAT)